# Can't pass AudioQueueRef inout parameter to AudioQueueNewOutput in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, core-audio

Here is my code:

```
var queue: AudioQueueRef
error = AudioQueueNewOutput(&dataFormat, 
AQOutputCallback, 
&player, 
nil, 
nil, 
0, 
&queue) // This gives me an error
```

I get an error associated with the `queue` variable: "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'AudioQueueRef' to 'AudioQueueRef?' requires a temporary". `AudioQueueNewOutput` requires that parameter to be of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef?>`. I don't know how to implement that conversion.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says that `AudioQueueRef` must be `inout` parameter means the same variable will change it's value anytime to new or old. So, you must define it as an `Optional` like below:

```
var queue: AudioQueueRef? 

var error = AudioQueueNewOutput(&dataFormat, 
AQOutputCallback, 
&player, 
nil, 
nil, 
0, 
&queue)
```

Let me know, if you still face any issues.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!